# How to get readonly-item type from an array in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How to get `readonly item array` from an array constant?

```js
const const basicValueTypes = [{
  value: 'number',
  label: 'Number'
},{
  value: 'boolean',
  label: 'Boolean'
}];

type ReadonlyItemArray = ???

type ReadOnlyBasicValueTypes = ReadonlyItemArray<typeof basicValueTyeps>;
/*
↓↓↓↓
ReadOnlyBasicValueTypes = (
  {value: 'number', label: 'Number'}
| {value: 'boolean', label: 'Boolean'}
)
*/
```

Update:
I figure out that I can make every item `as const`:

```js
const basicValueTypes = [{
  value: 'number',
  label: 'Number'
} as const,{
  value: 'boolean',
  label: 'Boolean'
} as const];

type BasicValueTypes = typeof basicValueTypes[number]['value'];
// BasicValueTypes = "number" | "boolean"
```

But I still want to know is it possible to contrive above `ReadonlyItemArray` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `basicValueTypes` immutable (readonly), you can use `as const`.

```js
const basicValueTypes = [{
    value: 'number',
    label: 'Number'
}, {
    value: 'boolean',
    label: 'Boolean'
}] as const;
```

To get the type, you can use `typeof`:

```js
type Immutable = typeof basicValueTypes
```

To make literal type, you can use :

```js
type Literal = [number, string]
```

Also there is built in readonly array:

```js
type Arr = ReadonlyArray<string>

const arr:Arr=['a','b']
arr.push('c') // error
```

But you can't do smth like that:

```js
const ReadOnlyBasicValueTypes = ReadonlyItemArray<typeof basicValueTyeps>;
```

BEcause types are not constructors, like it is in F#, it is only types. TS compiler will remove them from source code, and you will receive pure js

**Update**

```js
 const basicValueTypes = [{
  value: 'number',
  label: 'Number'
},{
  value: 'boolean',
  label: 'Boolean'
}] as const;

type Basic = typeof basicValueTypes;
type Item = Basic[number] // check this type
```

Comment: Sorry, It should be `type` rather than `const`. I edited the post.